# Upgrading Jetpack Navigation causes compilation error to other libraries

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack, mapbox-android, android-jetpack-navigation

I was trying to **upgrade** **Jetpack Navigation** (Plugins(safeargs) and libraries(fragment,UI,)) from

```
android.arch.navigation:{library-name}:1.0.0-alpha06
```

**To**

```
androidx.navigation:{library-name}:2.0.0
```

But it causes compilation error where **imports** from `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-geojson` **fail to resolve**.

Any reason for this to happen ? My setup is :

- Android Studio 3.3 (Can't currently update to 3.4)
- kotlin version 1.3.0

Below are some **screenshots** of the build failure :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you actually [Migrate your project to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)? You can't use 2.0.0 versions of Navigation unless you've moved to AndroidX.

Comment: Yeah, I am using other jetpack libraries like appcompat, constraintlayout, paging etc

Comment: Are you using the `1.0.0` AndroidX versions of them? Or the `28.0.0` Support Library versions?

Comment: I am using 1.* versions, the only 28  number in my project is  compile and target sdk .  I am using appcomat :   androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05